# How can I make an nginx proxy fleet's upstreams see the original requester's host/ip when receiving proxied requests?

Tags: nginx

My upstream services are reporting that all requests are coming from our nginx proxies, which is causing some issues with ip-based throttling. I've already added the following to our config in hopes of mitigating this:

```
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # Since our requests technically come from mini router on box...
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;

        proxy_pass https://$destination;
```

But it's obviously not working. Is there a separate directive that I can use to ensure that our requests appear to originate with our actual clients rather than from the proxy fleet?

Comment: From  which IP the traffic comes to Nginx, there  is any other hopes or firewall?

i think you   have problem with  this line set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1; it should be some other IP.

Also you can look at   real_ip_recursive on;

Comment: Nginx is receiving requests from another router on-box, for various reasons. Hence 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe the key to solving X-Forwarded-For woes when multiple IPs are chained is the recently introduced configuration option, real_ip_recursive (added in nginx 1.2.1 and 1.3.0). From the [nginx realip docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html):

> If recursive search is enabled, an original client address that
>   matches one of the trusted addresses is replaced by the last
>   non-trusted address sent in the request header field.

nginx was grabbing the last IP address in the chain by default because that was the only one that was assumed to be trusted. But with the new real_ip_recursive enabled and with multiple set_real_ip_from options, you can define multiple trusted proxies and it will fetch the last non-trusted IP.

For example, with this config:

```
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```